# Insert elements of a list as last elements into lists in list in python

Tags: python, list, insert, extend

A list of lists

```
list1 = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
```

should be extended by

```
list2 = ['I','II','III']
```

so it becomes

```
list1 = [[1,'a','I'],[2,'b','II'],[3,'c','III']]
```

My attempt with

```
[i+j for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]
```

seems to be wrong. My current way is

```
list1 = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
list2 = ['I', 'II', 'III']
for x in range(0,len(list1)):
    list1[x].append(list2[x])
```

This is not an elegant way. What is a recommendable pythonic way, maybe with zip?

Comment: The recommended stackoverflowic way is to tackle the problem yourself and if you get stuck come back and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: @Mike Scotty: I understand. I added my way to show that there's a solution, but not a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with the help of zip i.e

```
[i+[j] for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]

[[1, 'a', 'I'], [2, 'b', 'II'], [3, 'c', 'III']]
```

Comment: Didn't know zip, great idea!

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @Dark's solution:

```
list1 = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]

list2 = ['I','II','III']

list3 = [sublist + [list2[i]] for i, sublist in enumerate(list1)]
print(list3)  # -> [[1, 'a', 'I'], [2, 'b', 'II'], [3, 'c', 'III']]
```

If you cannot guarantee that the 2 lists will have the same length, my approach would be slightly easier to tweak to keep it working.

- `list1` bigger than `list2`:

  ```
  list3 = [sublist + [list2[i] if i < len(list2) else None] for i, sublist in enumerate(list1)]
  ```
- `list2` bigger than `list1`:

  ```
  # no problem here
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You do this and it's perfectly fine:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i].append(list2[i])
```

Otherwise you could use that one liner:

```
[i+[list2[i[0] -1]] for i in list1]
```

But it's one of these things where anyone who will ever read your code won't understand in one read. I'd recommend the clearer first option that says what it does at first glance.

Comment: If `list1` is bigger than `list2` I doubt this would work, since you are using list1's lenght

Comment: I agree. But then in this example list1 is the list you want to match list2 against. For this use case you could never make up the rest of list1.

Comment: Yes atleast a `try` and `except` nobody wants to see an error popping up : )